# Shadow/Filter not working in ie after animation like fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Guys Need your help.
I have a shadow applied to Div thru CSS, but in ie shadow doesn't show with animation
like `.fadeIn` or `.show("slow")`
Initially Div hidden(display:none)
I also tried to apply style right after animation, but with now luck.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var obj = $('#message')
    //obj.show(); //Working
    obj.fadeIn("slow"); //NOT Working
    obj.addClass("shadow")
});
```

Here is my code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7CJv/8/)

Is anything can be done for ie or not?

Thanx  a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941356/jquery-fadein-fadeout-in-ie/1941567#1941567)

Just need to add this to my js or Plugin Code

```
jQuery.fn.fadeIn = function(speed, callback) { 
return this.animate({opacity: 'show'}, speed, function() { 
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)  
        this.style.removeAttribute('filter');  
    if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) 
        callback();  
});
```

};

Thank you [Nick Lowman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228049/nick-lowman)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because jquery removes filter attributes while animating opacity because IE cannot render them properly. You could add the filter attribute back in after the animation completes.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7CJv/10/